# Getting error in while writing spark-3 data frame to AWS S3

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am getting the following error when I am trying to write spark 3 dataframe to AWS s3.
But with some minor change when I am trying to write it with spark 2 dataframe to s3 I am able to do it.

SPARK 3 code:

```
    spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")
    spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
    spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
    spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")

    df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(path)
```

Error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o88.parquet.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.lookupPassword(S3AUtils.java:816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.lookupPassword(S3AUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.getAWSAccessKeys(S3AUtils.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.<init>(SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.createAWSCredentialProviderSet(S3AUtils.java:600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:781)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: are you sure this is the full stack trace? Please add everything you see in your logs here, not just what you think it relevant.

Comment: The error is suggesting you're missing guava jar in your Spark libraries... How did you install Spark? Which version?

Comment: you have an older version of guava than whatever the hadoop-aws module was built with. Switch to hadoop 3.3.5 binaries which has its private copy of guava and reimplemented that precondition check internally as it was so brittle